# How to fix grey squares showing on gltf model in a-frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf

When looking at a model in aframe I see strange squares on gltf model.

I try to make an AR HTML  to scan a marker and show model on top of it. When I check the model in gltf viewer online it's fine but looking through the webapp it has grey squares on it. Has anyone seen this before?

```
<a-scene embedded
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
    shadow="type: pcf"
    arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; 
displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

               <!-- add your models -->
        <a-asset-item id="animated-asset" 
         src="https://artshirtsonline.com/shanatova/models/test2.gltf"  > 
                   </a-asset-item>
                           </a-assets>
    <a-entity animation-mixer="loop: repeat" gltf-model='#animated-asset' 
            scale="1 1 1"
            shadow="cast: true"
            rotation="-90 0 0"></a-entity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up shadowMap.bias
You can adjust it to tune for shadow acne. Also make sure your shadow camera near and far closely match what your scene covers.

Comment: Thanks, Manthrax!
Do you have any example in code? what should I write in order to adjust it or the Camera near and far?
Thanks

Comment: I think I managed to correct it in a way with shadowBias..:) thank you!!

Comment: @Adam mind telling where did you adjust the bias property ? (the renderer object, mesh.material) ?

Comment: Under entity light